# Java Contains method returns false even after defining equals

Tags: java

I have a coordinate class and a list of coordinates. I have overriden the equals method for the coordinate class but when I use the contains on a list of coordinates I get false for a coordinate which is in the list.
Has anyone got an idea where I am going wrong? x and y values are ints.

```
public boolean equals(Coordinate c){
        return (this.x == c.getxCoordinate() && this.y == c.getyCoordinate());
    }
```

The list is below:

```
List safe_locs = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
```

The test is below:

```
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(safe_locs.contains(c));
System.out.println(safe_locs);
```

output is:

```
Coordinate[x: 0, y: 0]
false
[Coordinate[x: 0, y: 0], Coordinate[x: 1, y: 0], Coordinate[x: 0, y: 1], Coordinate[x: 3, y: 0], Coordinate[x: 0, y: 3]]
```

Comment: can you post the list you have?

Comment: Of what type are `x` and `y`? Are you sure `==` is the right choice? Furthermore, you did not override the `equals` method, you just overloaded it...

Comment: Please show the list in which you have stored the coordinated

Comment: if either `x` or `y` is not of primitive datatype, you need to use `equals` to compare them.

Comment: Are you also overriding hashCode?

Comment: If it's not really a List, you'd have problem if you didn't override the hashcode method as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `equals()` method is *overloading* [`equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), while it should *override* it:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(!(o instanceof Coordinate)) {
        return false;
    }
    Coordinate c = (Coordinate)o;
    return (this.x == c.getxCoordinate() && this.y == c.getyCoordinate());
    }
```

Unfortunately you must use downcasting. Notice the [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation - use it in the future to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 2):

I am aware that many readers will find this `equals` implementation style unacceptably condensed, but `equals` is a very standard, all-boilerplate method and, once you implement a couple hundred of them, you tend to appreciate this style more and more:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   Coordinate that;
   return this == o || o instanceof Coordinate 
     && this.x == (that = (Coordinate)o).getxCoordinate() 
     && this.y == that.getyCoordinate();
}
```

The point is, whatever implementation style you consistently use, you soon stop looking at the detailed program logic and only notice the salient features: what fields participate and by what means they are compared. As soon as you reach that point, the conciceness of this implementation shines. And if you're suspecting a bug, again—less code, less work to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have **overloaded** the `equals()` method **instead of overriding** it..

```
public boolean equals(Object o){

    if(!(o instanceof Coordinate)) {

        return false;
    }
    else{
    Coordinate c = (Coordinate)o;
    return (this.x == c.getxCoordinate() && this.y == c.getyCoordinate());
    }

    }
```